# Joomla Mysql Query Issue

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, where-clause

The two joomla tables                                                         :

```
uh46v_fb_sw_user_items  uh46v_comprofiler
id  userid              id  user_id cb_country  cb_intl_shipping
5   833                 833 833     de          ch|*|fr|*|de
6   833                 834 834     fr          ch|*|fr
11  835                 835 835     ch          ch|*|fr|*|de
10  834                 836 836     fr
```

The Joomla query :

```
$userIntlShip = 'ch,de,fr';
$userCountry = 'de';
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
->select($db->quoteName(array('i.id')))
->from($db->quoteName('uh46v_fb_sw_user_items', 'i'))
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('uh46v_comprofiler', 'c') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('c.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('i.userid') . ')')
->where($db->quoteName('c.cb_intl_shipping') . ' LIKE "%'.$userCountry.'%" AND ' . $db->quoteName('c.cb_country') . ' IN ('.$userIntlShip.')');
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList(); 
$list = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
$list[] = $row->id;
}
$authoritem = implode(',', $list); 
echo $authoritem;
```

Causes the following error :

> ```
> 1054 Unknown column 'ch' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT `i`.`id` FROM `uh46v_fb_sw_user_items` AS `i` INNER JOIN `uh46v_comprofiler` AS `c` ON (`c`.`id` = `i`.`userid`) WHERE `c`.`cb_intl_shipping` LIKE "%de%" AND `c`.`cb_country` IN (ch,fr,de)
> ```

Comment: You need to put quotes around the separate values of userIntlShip to avoid them being misinterpreted as columns.

Comment: I have done this : IN ("'.$userIntlShip.'")
No more error but the query should find some results but it doesn't.

Comment: Ideally do a select on both tables and put the output here. Maybe limit the actual data rows to 5, to keep it simple.

Comment: I have covered this topic very thoroughly: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22898/12352  Please post all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

First this

```
LIKE "%'.$userCountry.'%" AND '
```

should be

```
LIKE . $db->quote( '%'.$userCountry.'%') AND '
```

And then I would do the following:

```
$countryCodes = explode(",", $userIntlShip);
$countryCodes = implode('","', $countryCodes);

' IN ("'. $countryCodes .'")'
```

or even better just start with 
`$userIntlShip = array('ch','de','fr');`

Because then you can pull the list from the database and skip the exploding.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume the double-quotes around your `LIKE "%de%"` are causing this issue.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/5127499) and try using single quotes instead.

Comment: Some db's use double quotes for wrapping string values.  Firebird is one (off the top of my head), I'm sure there are others.  The real problem is that the comma-delimited string is being treated as comma-delimited columns -- this is clearly not right.  I have covered this topic fully on JSE, see my comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it like

$userIntlShip = **"'ch','de','fr'";**

Because here your query work like one string.
as **where country like ('ch,de,fr');**

Correct query is like
**Where country like ('ch','de','fr');**